# QT QML is not displaying properly

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2017, qml

I'm fairly new to using QT and I'm having issues with displaying the application window which I'm creating in a .qml file. I used a tutorial from the QT youtube channel as a starting point. When I run the application, a window does appear on screen, however, it is not to the specified dimensions, nor does it reflect what has been written in the qml (based on the outcome from the tutorial). I am using VS2017 with the QT plugin and have got buttons and windows to display using .ui files. What am I doing wrong with the implementation here?

qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtPositioning 5.12
import QtLocation 5.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow
{
    id: root
    width : 700
    height : 700
    visible : true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

Action
{
    id: actionNew
    text: qsTr("&New")
    shortcut: StandardKey.New
    icon.name: "document-new"
    onTriggered: area.placeholderText = "To do = New"
}

Action
{
    id: actionOpen
    text: qsTr("&Open")
    shortcut: StandardKey.Open
    icon.name: "document-Open"
    onTriggered: area.placeholderText = "To do - Open"
}

    Action
{
    id: actionSave
    text: qsTr("&Save")
    shortcut: StandardKey.Save
    icon.name: "document-Save"
    onTriggered: area.placeholderText = "To do - Save"
}

menuBar: MenuBar
{
    Menu 
    {
        title: "File"
        MenuItem {action: actionNew}
        MenuItem {action: actionOpen}
        MenuItem {action: actionSave}
    }
}

header: ToolBar
{
    RowLayout
    {
        ToolButton {action: actionNew}
        ToolButton {action: actionOpen}
        ToolButton {action: actionSave}
    }
}

TextArea
{
    id: area
    anchors.fill: parent
}
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QtQuick/QQuickView>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickItem>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QQuickView views;
    views.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/QTKM/main.qml")));
    views.show();


    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Are there any error messages? For me it displays the file menu, the three buttons and the `TextArea` in which I can type... (only thing I had to do was to change 5.12 to 5.11 because that's the version I'm using)

Comment: No error messages at all, everything runs, just not much happens.

Answer (score 0):

Testing your code I've seen that a second blank window appears.

To fix it I've changed the main to this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

Using `QQmlApplicationEngine` instead of `QQuickView`.

Comment: I've tried this and the program just closes, the output log states; "qrc:/QTKM/main.qml:25 IDs cannot start with an uppercase letter". I know it's because of the rootObject being empty, is this possibly why?

Comment: @MrPurple Line 25 of the qml file you've shared with us only contains a closing brace and the all the id's seem fine. Have you checked that the correct file name is being loaded (in C++)?

Comment: @TrebuchetMS It's the same ID that worked before when i was able to display a window with a text field. Unless i'm messing something up big time.

Comment: Have you changed your code? As @TrebuchetMS says it should be fine with the same code as you posted.

Comment: Haven't changed it at all :/ I made a new project and have placed the code in it, it works fine in that one.

Comment: @MrPurple using exactly the same Qml and C++ that you posted?

Comment: Yeah, i literally copy and pasted my code into the new project.